# Testing page for entry - List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: soql, unit-test, pagereference

This is the code for a page launched from an Event. It links the Event to a custom object Business_trip__c via a junction object Trip_meeting__c using the Event's ID as a text key. 
I am having issue running the test - I think I am not properly setting the page and am returning the titular error "List has no rows for assignment to SObject" for the EventIdString query.

Class:

```
public class NewTripMeetingExtension {

    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public trip_meeting__c TM {get;set;}
    public List <Event> EventId {get;set;}
    public String EventIdString {get;set;}
    public String EventReference {get;set;}

    public NewTripMeetingExtension (ApexPages.StandardController StandardController) {
        sc = standardController;

        EventIdString = (String)[select id from Event where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId'))].Id;
        Eventreference= [select subject from Event where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId'))].subject;
        TM = new Trip_meeting__c ();
        TM.Meeting__c=EventIdString;

    }

    public PageReference Cancel(){
        PageReference cancelUrl=new PageReference('/'+EventIdString);
        return cancelUrl;
    }

    public PageReference Save(){
        PageReference SaveUrl=new PageReference('/'+EventIdString);
        Trip_meeting__c TM1 = (trip_meeting__c)sc.GetRecord();
        TM1.Meeting__c=EventIdString;
        Database.insert(TM1, false);
        return SaveUrl;
    }


}
```

Test Code:

```
@isTest
public class testNewTripMeetingExtension {
     static testMethod void  testNewTripMeeting(){


        Account acc = new Account(Name='Abce');
        insert acc;

        Account a = new Account (name='Banson Quixotics');
        Insert a;

        Business_trip__c BT = new Business_trip__c (name='Name', Location__c='location', Start_date__c =System.today(), End_Date__c=System.today());
        insert BT;

        Event TestEvent = new Event ();
        TestEvent.subject='meeting subject';
        TestEvent.ActivityDate =date.today();
        TestEvent.ActivityDateTime = system.now();
        TestEvent.DurationInMinutes=12;
        TestEvent.Business_trip__c=BT.id;
        TestEvent.WhatId=a.id;
        TestEvent.Description='here are the notes in the field required to be there';
        inSert TestEvent;    

        Trip_meeting__c TM = new Trip_meeting__c();
        TM.Business_Trip__c=BT.id;
        Tm.Meeting__c = String.valueOf(TestEvent.id);
        Insert TM;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.NewTripMeetingEntry;   

         Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
         pageRef.getParameters().put('?EventId=',TestEvent.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(TestEvent);
         NewTripMeetingExtension  controller = new NewTripMeetingExtension(sc);

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('?EventId=',TestEvent.id);
```

to

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('EventId',TestEvent.id);
```

You don't have to pass ?, = and & when setting.

Answer (score 2):

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('?EventId=',TestEvent.id);
```

instead try this

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('EventId',TestEvent.id);
```

this will solve your issue..